# Flutter web run in chrome?

Tags: flutter

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
Failed to launch browser after 3 tries. Command used to launch it: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --user-data-dir=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tools.d39b26cf\flutter_tools_chrome_device.96f3921c --remote-debugging-port=55848 --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-extensions --disable-popup-blocking --bwsi --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --disable-default-apps --disable-translate http://localhost:55815
Failed to launch browser. Make sure you are using an up-to-date Chrome or Edge. Otherwise, consider using -d web-server instead and filing an issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
```

Comment: as for the error, try to upgrade your browser

Comment: browser also updated, but still that issue is coming

Comment: cant  say, if there are no others setup or make a copy of the project, and use `flutter create .`

Comment: already I tried but not working, all the web projects are not working in debug mode only in chrome but it's working fine in edge

Comment: try `flutter run -d chrome`

Comment: still same issue

Answer (score 1):

```
 flutter config --enable-web
```

Add this

Comment: Thank u for your response, But it;s not working for me, It's already working fine in microsoft edge but not working in chrome and  api is not working in microsoft edge  also flutter v-3.3.4